# Calculate quarterly compound interest from yearly simple interest

Tags: excel-formula

Let's say the yearly simple interest is 10% on a principal of $100. At the end of one year, the new principal is $110. I'm trying to calculate the compound interest equivalent so by the end of the 4th quarter, the new principal should still be $110. In the example below, I'm compounding quarterly (which is incorrect) and I'm ending up with $110.38. How do I modify the formula so I end up at $110?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is technically maths rather than programming but, since Excel is a crossover, we can possibly let it through :-)

The formula for calculating initial capital plus cumulative interest on an amount of `b` at `r%` per period over `n` periods is:

> `newb = b * (1 + r/100)n`

Hence, the formula for getting 10% per year with quarterly interest over that year is (using `1.1`, since `newb` must be 10% higher than `b`):

> `1.1 = (1 + r/100)4`

So, let's just give the expression `1 + r/100` the term `mult` for now, and we can work out the rate from that later:

```
   mult^4 = 1.1
=> mult = ∜(1.1)
=> mult = 1.024113 (roughly)
```

We can then calculate that the desired interest rate is `2.4113%` (by starting with `mult`, subtracting one, then multiplying by a hundred).

And here's the table to prove it (interest values are rouned):

```
 Current              New
 Balance  Interest  Balance
 -------  --------  -------
  100.00      2.41   102.41
  102.41      2.47   104.88
  104.88      2.53   107.41
  107.41      2.59   110.00
             -----
             10.00
```

You can see that you reach the 10% increase at the end of the fourth quarter.

---

In Excel, assuming `A1` holds the desired annual interest rate (like 10) and `B1` holds the number of periods in a year (like 4), you can calculate the periodic interest rate with:

```
= 100 * (power (1 + a1 / 100, 1 / b1) - 1)
```

as per the following screenshot (which also has the four quarterly calculations):

[image]

The formulae for the tabular cells are, if you're interested:

```
  +  A  +           B           +   C
3 | 100 | =ROUND(a3*$c$1/100,2) | =a3+b3
4 | =c3 | =ROUND(a3*$c$1/100,2) | =a4+b4
5 | =c4 | =ROUND(a3*$c$1/100,2) | =a5+b5
6 | =c5 | =ROUND(a3*$c$1/100,2) | =a6+b6
```

Feel free to use them as you see fit.

Comment: Thanks so much for your help. I'm planning to drag down the formula across rows and add up with a similar table you generated (the one with quarterly interest and new balance). What would be the formula in that case? Edit: I figured it out. I basically needed to use the new balance while calculating the interest for the next quarter.

Comment: @tempid, have added that detail now.

Answer (score 1):

With your current setup:

In `B5`: `=B2*(1+B1)^(1/4)`

In `B6` and drag down: `=B5*(1+B$1)^(1/4)`.

[image]